# Tensorflow Hanging on Google Compute Engine Using nohup

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a TensorFlow model that I estimate will take roughly 11 hours. As such, I would like to use nohup so I can exit my terminal keep the process running. I use the following command to do so:

`nohup python3 trainModel.py > log.txt &`

My model appears to be running as normal, but gets hung up with the last message outputted being:

`2020-01-22 19:06:24.669183: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0`

It is normal for my model to output this, however when I am not using nohup, the rest of the code still executes. What do I need to do to have this command run as it does when I am not using nohup?

Answer (score 0):

could you send the exit status code of the execution?  echo $?

This will help to get an exact idea of the error

Furthermore, can you try to send the standard error output to the log.txt file, for instance

nohup python3 trainModel.py  2> log.txt &

Standard output will be redirected to the nohup file and log.txt will contain the standard output error

I Hope this helps

Comment: No exceptions are being thrown, and there is no actual error, the model seems to just be 'stuck' on the line in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute paths in your execution instead of relative paths